# NGINX APACHE setup

Tags: nginx

In a situation with subdomains, how would I make a rewriter that gets all port 80 calls for a given subdomain and rewrites them to HTTPS?

Right now, my setup fails because Apache already has the IP:port X.X.X.X:80 for http://www.site.tld.

Is it even possible to do in NGINX http://myothersubdomain.site.tld:80 be rewritten to https://myothersubdomain.site.tld:443 ?

Comment: Are you looking to do this with nginx, apache, or both? Or are just looking for whichever works?

Comment: I have apache serving requests for the www (and other) subdomains on port 80, and I'd like to serve one specific subdomain with NGINX on port 443, and redirect incoming requests on port 80 for that subdomain to port 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both nginx and apache bound to port 80 on your server.

If you want to do that then I'd advise having nginx bound to port 80, and it proxying requests through to apache on another port

In terms of redirecting all request for an http://* url to https:// url setting up a server in the nginx config like follow

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    myothersubdomain.site.tld;
       rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

will to the trick

Comment: That's more or less the code I have for the redirecting indeed (listen *:80, to be precise).

Comment: If you have multiple IPs on your server you could bind apache to one IP and nginx to the other, which would open it up on port 80. Otherwise you could set up handling for http://myothersubdomain.site.tld in apache and just have nginx listen on port 443 (if apache isn't listening on that) and redirect from there. eg: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Comment: Just to confirm I understand your answer: *it's impossible to set up a selective bind for that port that would respond with NGINX or Apache based on the subdomain for a given port, and the solution is to do proxying*. Can I set Apache (who's the main server here) to do the proxying?

Comment: You can set apache as the proxy, but nginx is much lighter weight if you want to do proxying. However look at my suggestion of apache on port 80 handling requests and redirect subdomain to nginx on port 443, as that might be the simplest solution.

Comment: OK, clear for me. Thanks for the help! I actually used this solution for the redirect, but it works out the same ^^ https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: Consider using `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` instead of `rewrite`. See http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites